# Tiny error mark on my .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I got a tiny little red underlining in one of my Razor `@helper` and when I hover on it it never shows anything. I remembering having had this in the past and sometimes it mysteriously disappears, do you know what it is? Here is a picture, it's just by the `continue` statement.

[image]

Pls help me help this helper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In razor, in cshtml file every if else codes should  be inside `{}`